# How to get total result count when setFrom is used in elasticsearch QueryBuilders?

Tags: java, spring-boot, elasticsearch

I am creating pagination using elasticsearch QueryBuilders. I am using setFrom to get limited results for pagination. but I need total result count to create total page links in pagination as per result. How can i get total count before setFrom is applied to query? or I have to write same query again to get total count without setFrom and size?

this is my query

```
BoolQueryBuilder query = QueryBuilders.boolQuery();
for (String key : brands) {
    query.must(QueryBuilders.matchQuery("brand", key));
}

// search term
query.must(QueryBuilders.queryStringQuery(pSearchTerm + "*")
        .lenient(true).field("name"));

// price range
query.filter(QueryBuilders.rangeQuery("unit_price").from(min)
        .to(max));

SearchResponse searchresponse = client.prepareSearch("product")
        .setTypes("product").setQuery(query).setFrom(from).setSize(20)
        .setExplain(true).execute().actionGet();

SearchHit[] results = searchresponse.getHits().getHits();
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The number you're looking for is `hits.total` which you can get from:

```
long total = searchresponse.getHits().getTotalHits();
```

Comment: I should have search more before asking.

Comment: No worries, everyone here is either here to help or to learn ;-)

Answer (score 2):

No you don't have to write the query again. Just use

`searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits()`

Answer (score 2):

The SearchHits object provides global information about all hits.

So you need the following to get total count:

```
long totalCount = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits();
```

You can look at the [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/client/java-rest/current/java-rest-high-search.html) for such other needs.

Answer (score 1):

You may have to execute one more query to get total hits count. Have a look at:
[Counting number of documents using Elasticsearch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25739888/counting-number-of-documents-using-elasticsearch)

Comment: No, another query is not required. Check the answers below.

Comment: Check what OP is asking **How can i get total count before setFrom is applied to query?**

Comment: I think there's no reason to build a pagination before the first results come back. At that time you know how many results you're getting using `getTotalHits()` and can build the pagination based on that for the next queries. In the first query, theOP must use `setFrom(0)` to get the first 20 results back.

Comment: Since OP wants to create links to navigate across pages you can not say user to click on 1st link before clicking others.

Comment: No but since the query contains `pSearchTerm` I assume that the user first has to input something to trigger the search, right? even if the input is empty in which case he will want to match all names.