# How to get Total hits for an ES query after setting from and size field

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch

```
searchSourceBuilder.query(query).sort(sb).from(fromField).size(sizeField);
searchRequest.indices(elasticsearchUserIndex).source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = elasticSearchConfig.client().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
Long totalCount = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits();
List<Map<String, Object>> list = new ArrayList<>();
for (SearchHit value: hits) {
    list.add(value.getSourceAsMap());
    }
```

That is the code I'm using. Once I've set the from and the size parameter I get the hits according to the size set. But to add the total page count in response I need the total hits for that query.

[How to get total result count when setFrom is used in elasticsearch QueryBuilders?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53909454/how-to-get-total-result-count-when-setfrom-is-used-in-elasticsearch-querybuilder)

Tried to use the solution from that thread but I'm getting total hits as 0 even though I get the hits according to the size.
totalCount is returning 0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set `track_total_hits` to `true` and you will be able to get total hits for response.

```java
SearchSourceBuilder searchSourceBuilder = new SearchSourceBuilder();
searchSourceBuilder.query(QueryBuilders.matchAllQuery()).from(0).size(10);
searchSourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);
searchRequest.source(searchSourceBuilder);
Long totalCount = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits();
```

Comment: `searchSourceBuilder.query(query).sort(sb).from(fromField).size(sizeField);
searchSourceBuilder.trackTotalHits(true);
searchRequest.indices(elasticsearchUserIndex).source(searchSourceBuilder);
SearchResponse searchResponse = elasticSearchConfig.client().search(searchRequest, RequestOptions.DEFAULT);
SearchHit[] hits = searchResponse.getHits().getHits();
Long totalCount = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits();` Tried this but still giving me count as 0

Comment: which version of ES ? also see `searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits().value;` this line. I have added `value` in last

Comment: compile group: 'org.springframework.boot', name: 'spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch', version: '2.2.2.RELEASE'; I don't have an option to add value. Also when I look into the searchresponse object it shows totalHits as 0

Comment: I can't change the ES version, is there some other method to add with this ES version?

Comment: searchSourceBuilder.query(query).sort(sb).trackTotalHits(true).from(fromField).size(sizeField); tried this too just in case, no luck

Comment: Ya i can understand you can not change version but i am asking ES version because accordingly i will help

Comment: That is the spring dependency I'm using

Comment: Yes i know that you are using spring dependancy from exxception but i am asking Elasticsearch version. Because sometime due to version conflic issue occrs. Can you try with `matchAll` query and check. may be possible that for query youare passing for that no document available

Comment: So I was testing with size 2, I was getting 2 hits but I know for that query the total hits are 9. There are documents available for this query

Comment: I am not sure because same code i have run with `spring-boot-starter-data-elasticsearch` with version `2.2.2.RELEASE` and i am able to get hit count. it will be great if you can tell about Elasticsearch version. I have tested code on ES version 7.10

Comment: I'm checking my jars, it says ES client is 6.4.3 and spring-data-elasticsearch is 3.1.5 RELEASE.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/244292/discussion-between-aditya-k-and-sagar-patel).

Answer (score 0):

Changed my ES version to 7.3.0. With it had to update my rest-high-level-client to 7.3.0 as well.

references: https://discuss.elastic.co/t/issue-with-high-level-rest-client-api/195853

Answer (score 0):

with new Version client
here is how to get the total count

Long totalCount = searchResponse.getHits().getTotalHits().value;

this error popped up in idea java: long cannot be dereferenced