# ElasticSearch Count API vs SearchAPI with track_total_hits set to true

Tags: elasticsearch, search, count

I need to know the count of items in the ES index. Using the Search API, I can take the count from `hit.total` part of the response:

```json
"total": {
  "value": 467,
  "relation": "eq"
}
```

It's limited on default to 10'000 hits, so when

```json
"total": {
  "value": 10000,
  "relation": "gte"
}
```

I know two solutions to get the exact number of this count:

1. Set `track_total_hits=true` for a request to the Search API. According to the documentation, it comes with the cost.
2. Make another call to Count API.

Do you know which solution is better? In the first option, I'll make only a single HTTP call do the Elastic Search. In the second one, I need two HTTP calls. Do you know if the Count API is significantly better than `track_total_hits=true` flag?

Answer (score 3):

`track_total_hits` is an optimization which doesn't affect queries which yield fewer than 10K docs. In other words, it wouldn't make your query which returns 467 docs any faster.

Now, as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25743668/8160318), `_count` *should* be faster because there's no ranking and no expensive `_source` retrieval. So go with `_count` if you care about saving speed at every turn.

But keep in mind that `_count` doesn't support the `from`, `size`, or `aggregations` parameters — only the [`query` body parameter](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html#search-count-request-body) or the [lucene URL parameter `q`](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-count.html#search-count-api-query-params).